# Where to see all options for a windows command?

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line

I wanted to get list of file names from a folder, and I got the solution from this post [How do I copy all file names in a folder to notepad?](https://superuser.com/questions/490306/how-do-i-copy-all-file-names-in-a-folder-to-notepad).

I would like to know where to get info of all command line switches/options available for a **single** windows cmd (not the whole list of commands). I tried `dir -h`/`dir --help`/`dir help` but nothing helps. As you get for commands in unix, it would be helpful to know.

Comment: Hi, Open a command prompt window in your machine and then type "help" without quotes. This will list all the commands with its definition.

Comment: @charlie The question to mentioned is about getting to know the commands available. My question is to get to know the options of a particular command... Hence it's not a duplicate.

Comment: It is close, but I see what you are saying. Vote retracted.

Answer (score 2):

mtk, your answer is only partly correct.  `HELP` only works for system commands that are listed when you run `HELP` without an operand.  There are many commands/utilities not listed in HELP for which help is available with `/HELP` or `/?` and network commands require the use of `NET HELP` or `/HELP`.  The `/?` switch works for essentially everything that is documented, but for a very small set of network commands it only provides the parameters.

- **`HELP` and `/?` work for everything listed in HELP.**  Except that on my Windows 7 Home Edition system for some reason `GRAFTABL` has an entry in help but appears not to exist (it's there on the Enterprise Edition I use at work); all other commands that are documented in `HELP` have help.  Contrary to what James suggests in his comment to your own answer, if `HELP <command>` works then `<command> /?` also works, the reverse, however, is not true.  Additionally, two of the documented commands, `DISKPART` and `FSUTIL` require administrative privileges to even obtain the help (and `DISKPART` fails silently if you aren't an administrator).
- **Network commands require `/HELP` or `/?`** For network commands, it gets a little complicated.  To obtain help for a network commands in the `NET <command>` format, such as `NET USE`, you can enter `NET HELP USE` or `NET USE /HELP`; `NET USE /?` will return the syntax only.  However, for other network commands, such as `FINGER`, `IPCONFIG`, and `NBTSTAT`, `<command> /HELP` and `<command> /?` return identical results.  For still others, such as `HOSTNAME`, the two helps provide different information, the `/?` switch provides help and the `/HELP` switch provides some (very limited) guidance on setting hostnames (at least on my system).
- **There are many system commands for which `/?` works but `HELP` doesn't.**  There are some system commands that are not documented in `HELP` but for which you can obtain help with the help switch `<command> /?` (i.e. `HELP <command>` does not work).  Normally Windows will tell you if you use `HELP <command>` with these commands that you should try `/?`.  Examples are some commands that are relics from prior versions of windows such as `BOOTCFG` (used in Windows XP, but in Vista and Windows 7 you use `BCDEDIT`).  There are also some commands, such as `DEFRAG` that are treated more as utilities, rather than commands, in the documentation, that have help available but again only with `/?`.  `WINSAT` is an example of a command that requires `/?` for help but fails silently if not run as an administrator.  Apparently wherever `HELP <command>` doesn't work `<command> /HELP` is possible as an alternative, just like with network commands (for example `DEFRAG /HELP` works).

One oddball, `SC` responds to all of `HELP SC`, `SC /HELP`, and `SC /?` providing the same help but in all three cases the help begins with an error.

You can find a rather comprehensive list of commands [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754340.aspx), though a lot depends on how you define a command.  Any .EXE could be treated as a command and you'll notice the compendium at the link includes traditional "commands", "command line utilities", system tools, and invocations for programs such as `PowerShell` and `PowerShell_ISE`.  Note, command line help doesn't work for some programs that open in the GUI environment, such as `PowerShell_ISE` (which is why my fourth sentence, above, says "essentially").  Online help suggests it should work but it doesn't (the ISE actually misinterprets `/?` as an operand and tries to load the file `/?`.  Also, note, although the descriptions at the link are frequently better than in help, the OSs to which they apply are not always accurate (e.g. PowerShell_ISE says it applies only to Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012; however, PowerShell_ISE is available in Windows 7.

The bottom line is that generally `/?` will get you help if there is any.  For a few network commands, namely those that start with `NET <command>`, you should use `/HELP` for more detail.

Comment: [How to gain access to GRAFTABL and how to use it?](https://superuser.com/q/1343292/241386)

Answer (score 1):

Got it, typing `help` gives all available commands, and typing `help <cmd-name>` give all options.

e.g.

```
> help
For more information on a specific command, type HELP command-name
ASSOC          Displays or modifies file extension associations.
ATTRIB         Displays or changes file attributes.
BREAK          Sets or clear
....
```

and

```
> help dir
Displays a list of files and subdirectories in a directory.

DIR [drive:][path][filename] [/A[[:]attributes]] [/B] [/C] [/D] [/L] [/N]
  [/O[[:]sortorder]] [/P] [/Q] [/R] [/S] [/T[[:]timefield]] [/W] [/X] [/4]

  [drive:][path][filename]
              Specifies drive, directory, and/or files to list.

  /A          Displays files with specified attributes.
  attributes   D  Directories                R  Read-only files
               H  Hidden files               A  Files ready for archiving
               S  System files               I  Not content indexed files
               L  Reparse Points             -  Prefix meaning not
  /B          Uses bare format (no heading information or summary).
  /C          Display the thousand separator in file sizes.  This is the
              default.  Use /-C to disable display of separator.
  /D          Same as wide but files are list sorted by column.
```

Comment: most commands (but not all) also support `<command> /?`