# How to gain access to GRAFTABL and how to use it?

Tags: command-line

While working on a `CMD` documentation extractor, it came to my attention that `GRAFTABL` is listed by `HELP` but "is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file." This leads to two questions:

- How can `GRAFTABL` be used, or is there a replacement?
- How can documentation for the command be retrieved?

**Reference:**

- [A: Where to see all options for a windows command?](https://superuser.com/a/862114/66838)
- `import os, subprocess; print('Pass' if all(code in {0, 1} for code in ((print(word), os.system(f'echo {word} >> complete_help.txt'), os.system(f'help {word} >> complete_help.txt'))[2] for word in (line.split(None, 1)[0] for line in subprocess.Popen('help', stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read().decode('latin_1').splitlines() if line) if word.isalpha() and word.isupper())) else 'Fail')`

Comment: I've just about to ask the same question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've discovered a bit of legacy code/data that hasn't been cleaned up. The command is no longer needed or appropriate, as CMD no longer distinguishes between "graphics mode" and "text mode"; that more-or-less ended with Windows 95, and was definitely no longer a thing in Windows XP.

Comment: It was (is) still available in Windows XP as well as Windows Server.

Comment: @DavidPostill - I seem to remember it not existing in Windows XP - although on reflection, it makes sense that it would still have it, to support legacy DOS program, which it did directly (without requiring a VM or DOSBox).

Answer (score 2):

#### How can GRAFTABL be used, or is there a replacement?

> The graftabl command allows the display to show extended characters in graphics mode from a specific code page. Most monitors do not need the graftabl command to be loaded.
>
> The graftabl command is an external command and is available in the
> below Microsoft operating systems as graftabl.com.
>
> - MS-DOS 3.0 through MS-DOS 5.0
> - Windows 95
> - Windows 98
> - Windows ME
> - Windows NT
> - Windows 2000
> - Windows XP
>
> Examples:
>
> ```
>     graftabl 437
> ```
>
> Loads graftabl for the United States.

Source [MS-DOS graftabl command help](https://www.computerhope.com/graftabl.htm)

It also seem to be available on [WindowsServer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/graftabl).

The functionality has been replaced by [Chcp - Change Code Page - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/chcp.html):

```
chcp 437
```

Comment: Thanks for noting that `CHCP` is a replacement!