# How to copy all file names which are in folders into notepad?

Tags: window, notepad

I have 50 folders present in one folder.

In that 50 folders, In Each Folder contains 1 mp3 file (some folders contains even more than 1 mp3 file).

I want to copy all mp3 file names into notepad.

How to complete this task in Win 7?

I gone through This [question](https://superuser.com/questions/490306/how-do-i-copy-all-file-names-in-a-folder-to-notepad), But it is differ from my post.

Comment: That question is actually pretty similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open a command prompt (cmd, possibly by shift right clicking and selecting "Open Command Prompt Here") and run:

```
dir /B /S *.mp3 > mp3list.txt
```

This will get you a list (including the full path) of all MP3s in that folder and its sub-folders and save it to the file `mp3list.txt` in the current folder.

Without the `> mp3list.txt` the list is going to be displayed in the cmd window. You can copy it by left clicking and marking all the text followed by a right click (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> doesn't work here!). After that the text will be in your Clipboard and you can paste it using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.

Comment: please add this lines dir /B /S *.mp3 > filelist.txt to complete the answer.

Comment: @user45331 right-click -> select all -> Ctrl+C works too and does dont create a file.

Comment: I did as it might be a good idea. Though the original question states she/he wants to copy it. So without the redirect that would easily be possible. Thanks for pointing it out as am improvement. Thanks both of you.