# Issue in listing all the files of a directory to notepad

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

**Using [already an answer here](https://superuser.com/a/490314/1222458)**

And **it works** with just one difference. Running `dir /B` returns all the file's names correctly.

Now when I run `dir /B > someFile.txt` it creates a `.txt` file but also append the name `someFile` at the end of the file.

[image: Please see this]

This behaviour is just confusing me a bit. This means that it creates the `.txt` file before listing the files name.

Shouldn't it be the other way around? Please enlighten.

Also, I find `cmd` very intriguing and want to learn more about it and it's commands. Can you please refer some guides/articles/docs for the same. That would be really helpful. Thanks :)

Comment: This is Microsoft owns documentation. It can be useful. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/windows-commands

Comment: Did you mean that dir /B > someFile.txt will also create a somefile.txt file in the txt file?  If yes, I think this is a normal behavior. If you want to know about DIR command, please refer to the following link:https://www.howtogeek.com/363639/how-to-use-the-dir-command-in-windows/

Comment: Thanks for your time. Please see the updated question now. I don't want this `someFile.txt` at the end of the list. This is the file in which I'm writing the list of files. I hope I'm clear and also thanks for the link. @Candy

Comment: Thanks a lot @akane.

Comment: Cmd.exe, although it still functions, is pretty much obsolete. Powershell is now the standard command line application on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I think easiest way to get rid of the `someFile.txt` inside it's self is to give an absolute or relative path to another directory.

For example, let's say you run `dir` inside `C:\Users\bosse`. Then you can choose to locate the file somewhere else outside this directory and it will not be included. Let's say in your `C:\tmp` directory if you have.

Using absolute path:
`C:\Users\bosse>dir /B > C:\tmp\someFile.txt`

Using relative path:
`C:\Users\bosse>dir /B > ..\..\tmp\someFile.txt`

In these case when you open `C:\tmp\someFile.txt` it shall not contain it's own name.

Here you can read more absolute and relative path in case you are not familiar with that.
[Windows file path formats](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/file-path-formats)

Even though the the target file do not need to exist and will be created, please notice that the directory path must exist in advance.
`dir` can be used to check path exists.
`dir [<drive>:]<path>`
If directory path do not exist it can be created by [mkdir](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mkdir).
`mkdir [<drive>:]<path>`

Comment: Thanks for your time. But, `dir /B > D:\my\folders\to\go\through\somefile.txt`, as you suggested, states `The system cannot find the path specified.` (because there's no file there with such a name right now). I hope what I did is what you meant. what else can I try next? Thanks again.

Comment: I believe this is related to the directory path do not exists. Not related to that the file, since file will be auto created. I updated the answer. You can check if the path exists by `dir D:\my\folders\to\go\through\ `. If it do not exist you can either redirect to other directory path that exist or you can create the directory path by `mkdir`